# "Two-scale" network?

Tags: soft-question, network

I've read that networks can be:

- random (Erdős–Rényi model),
- scale-free (Albert–Barabási model),
- small-world (Watts–Strogatz model).

But can a real world network be “two-scale”, in the sense that its degree distribution only consists of two different degrees, for example $(5,5,5,5,4,4,4,...)$ where the number nodes of degree $4$ is equal to $9$?

Comment: Real world, no. But for a random network as you wish, yes, simply adapt the usual construction starting with half-edges attached to each vertex.

Comment: It can't be real world because it doesn't have a power law degree distribution? Would the degree distribution for a "two scale" network just be a line segment with negative slope?

Comment: *It can't be real world because it doesn't have a power law degree distribution?* – Many real networks do not have such a distribution and it is still up to debate to what extents observations of such distributions in real networks are a measurement artefact. The models you list are just that: models. Any given real network will substantially differ from the typical output of these models. (And note that I use *typical* here only because all of the models involve randomness and therefore can produce all sorts of things with a very low probability.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of “real-world networks” is not well defined. Usually, as soon as you find some kind of natural data, from which your network emerges it can be considered a real-world network. Most real-world data has certain properties that are significantly different from random networks (i.e., the Erdős–Rényi model), e.g., its degree distribution or the small-world property.

If you are asking whether there exists a graph that has that particular degree sequence, then the answer is *yes*, and here is an example given by its edge list:
$
[(0, 11), \;
 (0, 3), \;
 (0, 3), \;
 (0, 10), \;
 (0, 6), \;
 (1, 4), \;
 (1, 3), \;
 (1, 11), \;
 (1, 10), \;
 (1, 5), \;
 (2, 5), \;
 (2, 7), \;
 (2, 7), \;
 (2, 4), \;
 (2, 3), \;
 (3, 5), \;
 (4, 8), \;
 (4, 8), \;
 (5, 6), \;
 (6, 9), \;
 (6, 11), \;
 (7, 7), \;
 (8, 12), \;
 (8, 10), \;
 (9, 10), \;
 (9, 12), \;
 (9, 11), \;
 (12, 12)]$

In general, this is known as the [graph-realization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_realization_problem) and there are efficient (i.e. in polynomial time) algorithms that, given a degree sequence, can decide whether this sequence can be realized as a degree sequence of a graph or not.

Also note that networks can fall in much more than just these three categories, and the Watts–Strogatz model with $0$ randomness actually **does not** exhibit the small-world property.